# Having trouble determinating the definition domain of an aplication

Tags: linear-algebra

So let's say that I have this matrix:
$$
        A=\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 9\\
        3 & 7\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $x\neq{1}$ and I have to determinate the definition domain of the application $t\to f(tA)\in M_2(R)$.

I have tried to solve it with eigenvalues, but I don't realy know if I can continue it. The eigenvalues are: $\frac{9+\sqrt{133}}{2}$ and $\frac{9-\sqrt{133}}{2}$.
After this I've tryed to calculate $f(tA)$ and I got $f(tA)=(I-tA)^{-1}$ But I don't know how to calculate this either. Can someone explain me what the definition domain is and how to calculate it?

Comment: But aren't you done already? You need $I-tA$ to be invertible, which it is for all $t$ except for the eigenvalues.

Comment: @zipirovich I don't actualy understand what the definition domain of an aplication is.. That's what I want to know. A definition for that, I want to understand the exercise.. So can you explain why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to find all $t$ such that $f(tA)$ is well-defined. It's really the usual concept of the domain of a function, where in this particular example the function is $g(t)\colon\mathbb{R}\to M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined as $g(t)=f(tA)=(I-tA)^{-1}$. To be able to evaluate this matrix expression, you need to take the inverse of $I-tA$, so you need $I-tA$ to be invertible. And it is invertible for all $t$ except for the eigenvalues of $A$.